# Grunt import from external JSON

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

Using [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace#patternsjson) (or another alternative) I need to read an external JSON file and use it to match the key and replace with the value.

Example, this works:

```
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
            {
                json: {
                     "hello": "goodbye",
                }
            }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['index.html'], dest: 'production/'}
        ]
    }
},
```

However I need it to do something along the lines of:

```
assets: '<%= grunt.file.read("temp/assets.json") %>',
replace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            patterns: [
            {
                json: {
                    include: '<%= assets %>'
                }
            }
            ]
        },
        files: [
            {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['index.html'], dest: 'production/'}
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: It's not importing the external JSON, include doesn't work (just spits out the JSON into the html file).

I need to import the JSON into the task.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `grunt.file.read("temp/assets.json")` and not `'<%= grunt.file.read("temp/assets.json") %>'`?

Comment: You need to give example of what is input and what should be the output...

Comment: @Vishwanath The input is a standard JSON file from an external source however the task needs the JSON to be inline (within json: {}) so I need to be able to have a way of importing it in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grunt.file.readJSON()` (Ref: [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.readjson))

```
assets: grunt.file.readJSON('temp/assets.json');
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
        patterns: [
        {
            json: {
                include: '<%= assets %>'
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    files: [
        {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['index.html'], dest: 'production/'}
    ]
  }
}
```